# Rails select random record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know if I'm just looking in the wrong places here or what, but does active record have a method for retrieving a random object?

Something like?

```
@user = User.random
```

Or... well since that method doesn't exist is there some amazing "Rails Way" of doing this, I always seem to be to verbose. I'm using mysql as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails 4 I would extend `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  def random
    offset(rand(count))
  end
end
```

This way you can use scopes:

```
SomeModel.all.random.first # Return one random record
SomeModel.some_scope.another_scope.random.first
```

Answer (score 39):

Most of the examples I've seen that do this end up counting the rows in the table, then generating a random number to choose one. This is because alternatives such as `RAND()` are inefficient in that they actually get every row and assign them a random number, or so I've read (and are database specific I think).

You can add a method like the one I found [here](http://gist.github.com/358505#file_gistfile1.ru).

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def self.random
      if (c = count) != 0
        find(:first, :offset =>rand(c))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This will make it so any Model you use has a method called `random` which works in the way I described above: generates a random number within the count of the rows in the table, then fetches the row associated with that random number. So basically, you're only doing one fetch which is what you probably prefer :)

You can also take a look at [this rails plugin](http://github.com/grosser/random_records).

Comment: This is nice. I like it because it is additionally not ORM specific. Nice work, thanks!

Comment: in Rails 4.1, I had to use: `offset(rand(c)).first`

Answer (score 7):

We found that offsets ran *very* slowly on MySql for a large table. Instead of using offset like:

```
model.find(:first, :offset =>rand(c))
```

...we found the following technique ran more than 10x faster (fixed off by 1):

```
max_id = Model.maximum("id")
min_id = Model.minimum("id")
id_range = max_id - min_id + 1
random_id = min_id + rand(id_range).to_i
Model.find(:first, :conditions => "id >= #{random_id}", :limit => 1, :order => "id")
```

Comment: The last line is a little too verbose. This does the same thing (in Rails 3): 

`Model.where("id >= #{random_id}").first`

Comment: If any records have been deleted, then method does not generate uniformly distributed results, which is generally what one would expect. Imagine the case where ids 1-10 exist, except for id 5. In that case, the model with an id of 6 would be returned when the random number generator produces either a 5 or a 6 (20% of the time), whereas each of the other existing ids is selected only 10% of the time. Perhaps not a deal breaker, but something of which to be aware.

Answer (score 6):

Try using Array's [sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample) method:

```
@user = User.all.sample(1)
```

Comment: I like your answer that's some real ruby style

Comment: You should remove the (1), as this results in a singleton array. Using User.all.sample results in just one user

Comment: You definitely should not do this if you have a significant amount of data - it will attempt to load all users in memory. If you're on Rails 4 and Postgres, use `User.order("RANDOM()").limit(10)` (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/17373279/1298553).

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a named scope. Just throw this into your User model.

```
named_scope :random, :order=>'RAND()', :limit=>1
```

The random function isn't the same in each database though. SQLite and others use `RANDOM()` but you'll need to use `RAND()` for MySQL.

If you'd like to be able to grab more than one random row you can try this.

```
named_scope :random, lambda { |*args| { :order=>'RAND()', :limit=>args[0] || 1 } }
```

If you call `User.random` it will default to 1 but you can also call `User.random(3)` if you want more than one.

Comment: I've heard RAND() is really slow because it first fetches every record and then somehow chooses one, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @Blaenk: It *is* very slow on MySQL. I do not know about the implementation though.

Answer (score 2):

If you would need a random record but only within certain criteria you could use "random_where" from this code:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def self.random
      if (c = count) != 0
        find(:first, :offset =>rand(c))
      end
    end

    def self.random_where(*params)
      if (c = where(*params).count) != 0
        where(*params).find(:first, :offset =>rand(c))
      end
    end

  end
end
```

For e.g :

```
@user = User.random_where("active = 1")
```

This function is very useful for displaying random products based on some additional criteria

Comment: Rails 3 and active relation chaining takes care of this case. You could do just `User.random.where('active = 1')` without the need for an additional global method.

Comment: "find" method doesn't return Relation object, it returns either model object or an array :) , but! you could do this `User.where('active = 1').random` and this will work just fine... I don't know why I missed it :)

Comment: You are correct. Good eye. I thought one thing and typed another. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Strongly Recommend this gem for random records, which is specially designed for table with lots of data rows:

https://github.com/haopingfan/quick_random_records

Simple Usage:

`@user = User.random_records(1).take`

---

All other answers perform badly with large database, except this gem:

1. quick_random_records only cost `4.6ms` totally.

[image]

2. the accepted answer `User.order('RAND()').limit(10)` cost `733.0ms`.

[image]

3. the `offset` approach cost `245.4ms` totally.

[image]

4. the `User.all.sample(10)` approach cost `573.4ms`.

[image]

Note:  My table only has 120,000 users. The more records you have, the more enormous the difference of performance will be.

---

UPDATE:

Perform on table with 550,000 rows

1. `Model.where(id: Model.pluck(:id).sample(10))` cost `1384.0ms`

[image]

2. `gem: quick_random_records` only cost `6.4ms` totally

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best solution for getting random records from database.
RoR provide everything in ease of use.

For getting random records from DB use **sample**, below is the description for that with example.

Backport of Array#sample based on Marc-Andre Lafortune’s github.com/marcandre/backports/ Returns a random element or n random elements from the array. If the array is empty and n is nil, returns nil. If n is passed and its value is less than 0, it raises an ArgumentError exception. If the value of n is equal or greater than 0 it returns [].

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].sample     # => 4     
[1,2,3,4,5,6].sample(3)  # => [2, 4, 5]     
[1,2,3,4,5,6].sample(-3) # => ArgumentError: negative array size     
[].sample     # => nil     
[].sample(3)  # => []
```

You can use condition with as per your requirement like below example.

User.where(active: true).sample(5)

it will return randomly 5 active user's from  User table

For more help please visit : http://apidock.com/rails/Array/sample