# Rails how to randomly pick a row in a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I random pick a row in a table?

Example my table:

```
name   age 
Lars   24
Grete  56
Hans   56
```

I want to random pick a name.

Example:

```
@randomname = Model.where(:name 'Random')
```

And how do I only pick 1 random name each day. That I can use as a instant variable in view.

Comment: Are you picking a random column or row? This is slightly confusing...

Comment: Seems then that all the answers are trying to do random rows.

Comment: FYI, Rails beginner, columns are `name`, `age` and rows are `lars, grete, hans...` so your data has 2 columns and 3 rows. If you want random column, then you will get back text `name` or `age`, NOT it's *values*.

Comment: In that case you have a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641057/rails-select-random-record or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752231/random-record-in-activerecord.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@randomname = Model.order('rand()').limit(1).first.name
```

Comment: How do I create a random for a day. So it dos not create a random name each time I reload my browser

Comment: `Model.order('rand()').first.name` will be enough.  Limit 1 will be set automatically

Answer (score 3):

A random column in Rails 3 is simply:

```
Model.columns.sample.name
```

Comment: This is the winning ticket. I'm unsure of why he would need a random column though...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get random object 1 per day, so you should store it somewhere. You can store it:

- in separate file
- in separate model
- in the same model add rndm field

Lets implement the last one. It is quite easy. Imagine, that your `Model` called `User`. First, let's add new date field `rndm`:

```
rails g migration add_rndm_to_user rndm:date
rake db:migrate
```

Now we need to add some methods to your `User` model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.random
    rndm = find_by_rndm Date.today
    unless rndm
      update_all :rndm => nil
      rndm = self.order('rand()').first
      rndm.update_attribute :rndm, Date.today
    end
    rndm
  end
end
```

so now you can call `User.random` from your controller

Answer (score 0):

I have some Rails 2 code that shows the idea i think, and it's very easy to convert to rails 3 :

```
random_monsters = self.find(:all, :conditions=>["level > 0 and level < ? and monster_type='monster'", user_level+2])
random_monster = random_monsters[rand(random_monsters.length)]
```

I've also seen somebody in SO propose an offset way like :

```
offset = rand(Model.count)
rand_record = Model.first(:offset => offset)
```