# Better Way to Randomize (Ruby/Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, random

I'm currently using:

> @users = User.order("RANDOM()").limit(6)

to generate a list of 6 random users - however, this method takes a 1200ms toll on page load times. Is there a faster/more efficient way to call 6 random users?

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279706/select-random-row-from-an-sqlite-table/4740561#4740561 ?

Comment: have you considered this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641057/rails-select-random-record/3641112#3641112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the method described here:
[Rails select random record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641057/rails-select-random-record/3641112#3641112)

@ramc - Thank you for your comment. Load times are now much faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming auto increment ids, starting from 0 and that User objects are never deleted, the following should be quite fast:

`@users = (0..5).map { User.find(rand * User.count) }`

Comment: Also, it would be faster if cache the result of User.count. Excluded for brevity & clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a random offset & limit?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.random num = 1
    num.times.map { offset(rand(count)).limit(1) }
  end

end

@users = User.random(6)
```

I've used something similar to get single random instances from AR. You'd have to make it a bit smarter if you wanted to guarantee unique results.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a random Page of users instead. Consider this pagination call using [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/Kaminari-recipes)

```
User.order('created_at').page(rand(User.count)).per(6)
```

This will fire one count query and one query for the page of 6 Users

Answer (score -2):

You could try using array shuffle instead of using mysql random as it can be slow:

```
@users = User.all.shuffle[0..5]
```

After all, a collection of ActiveRecord objects is still just an Array

Comment: This code is valid, but the load times are the same. :(

Comment: This also loads the entire User collection - performance will get worse as the number of user records increases.

Comment: Loading the entire collection is not something you want to do, if the database does it you will not need to fetch every rows.