# How random is Rails' `sample` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to produce something close to the Fisher-Yates shuffle for randomness. I know underscore.js uses this technique on the `_.shuffle` method. In Rails, I use either

```
.sample
```

And sometimes I do it this way as its a little faster..

```
.order("RANDOM()").first
```

But just how random are these? Is there a better way to make this random?

Comment: Have you tried ruby's shuffle method? AFAIK it uses the Fisher–Yates shuffle. Also you might find this answer relevant if speed is your concern http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641057/rails-select-random-record/3641112#3641112 should be faster than `.order("RANDOM()")`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try this

```
prng = Random.new

prng.rand(100)       # => 42
```

Read about ruby's Random class.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Random.html#method-c-rand

Comment: Is that a better quality random though? Seems the same as the others. Noting that it doesn't seem to borrow from a Fisher-Yates shuffle.