# What's the 'Rails 4 Way' of finding some number of random records?

Tags: random, ruby-on-rails-4

`User.find(:all, :order => "RANDOM()", :limit => 10)` was the way I did it in Rails 3.

`User.all(:order => "RANDOM()", :limit => 10)` is how I thought Rails 4 would do it, but this is still giving me a Deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).load`). If you want to get an array of records from a relation, you can call #to_a (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).to_a`).
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You'll want to use the `order` and `limit` methods instead. You can get rid of the `all`.

For PostgreSQL and SQLite:

```
User.order("RANDOM()").limit(10)
```

Or for MySQL:

```
User.order("RAND()").limit(10)
```

Comment: Just a quick note, I had to use: `User.order("RAND()").limit(10)` as I am using a MySQL database.

Comment: Note that this is O(n^2) and bound to be unacceptable for any table bigger than a few rows. See the .offset(rand()) method by @maurimiranda below for the only sane solution in this thread.

Comment: `User.order("RANDOM()").limit(10)` worked for me on Postrgres and Rails 5.

Comment: For anybody who comes here from Rails 5.2+ you should wrap "RANDOM()" or "RAND()" in `Arel.sql()` because it's not on the safe value list.  However, it's safe to you, I assume.

Comment: An example with Arel.sql. `User.order(Arel.sql('random()')).limit(10)`

Answer (score 40):

As the random function could change for different databases, I would recommend to use the following code:

```
User.offset(rand(User.count)).first
```

Of course, this is useful only if you're looking for only one record.

If you wanna get more that one, you could do something like:

```
User.offset(rand(User.count) - 10).limit(10)
```

The `- 10` is to assure you get 10 records in case rand returns a number greater than *count - 10*.

*Keep in mind you'll always get 10 consecutive records.*

Comment: +1 Not only is the `offset` approach more versatile than the accepted answer but it's also faster when there are a lot of records. This is because `ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT $1` will **sort the entire table** then pick the first _n_ items. The sorting operation is likely `O(n * log n)` and sorting a large table not only reads that table but also involves reading and writing temporary files.

Comment: This worked for me, whereas `User.order("RANDOM()").limit(10)` did not; it always returned the same record. I'm using a **Postgresql** database and running **Rails 5**.

Comment: This would be the correct answer if the question was specific to finding *a* random record. But the question asks about finding random records in general. Finding a set of rows in order at random isn't really the same.

Comment: Please pay attention your table cannot have delete record, otherwise ID is not in seq.

Comment: It should be `User.offset(rand(User.count - 10)).limit(10)` instead of `rand(User.count) - 10` otherwise there is a chance you will end up with a negative index, which raises a `PG::InvalidRowCountInResultOffsetClause`.

Answer (score 23):

I think the best solution is really ordering randomly in database.
But if you need to avoid specific random function from database, you can use `pluck` and `shuffle` approach.

For one record:

```
User.find(User.pluck(:id).shuffle.first)
```

For more than one record:

```
User.where(id: User.pluck(:id).sample(10))
```

Comment: Nice. Even shorter: `User.find( User.ids.shuffle.first )`

Comment: `User.pluck(:id).shuffle` will load whole database ids in memory. Do not do this for tables with a lot of records

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest making this a scope as you can then chain it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :random, -> { order(Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('RANDOM', [])) }
end 

User.random.limit(10)
User.active.random.limit(10)
```

Answer (score 8):

While not the fastest solution, I like the brevity of:

`User.ids.sample(10)`

The `.ids` method yields an array of User IDs and `.sample(10)` picks 10 random values from this array.

Comment: Or if you just want the Models themselves, `User.all.sample(10)` will get them.

Answer (score 7):

Strongly Recommend this gem for random records, which is specially designed for table with lots of data rows:

https://github.com/haopingfan/quick_random_records

All other answers perform badly with large database, except this gem:

1. quick_random_records only cost `4.6ms` totally.

[image]

2. the accepted answer `User.order('RAND()').limit(10)` cost `733.0ms`.

[image]

3. the `offset` approach cost `245.4ms` totally.

[image]

4. the `User.all.sample(10)` approach cost `573.4ms`.

[image]

Note:  My table only has 120,000 users. The more records you have, the more enormous the difference of performance will be.

---

UPDATE:

Perform on table with 550,000 rows

1. `Model.where(id: Model.pluck(:id).sample(10))` cost `1384.0ms`

[image]

2. `gem: quick_random_records` only cost `6.4ms` totally

[image]

Comment: I keep getting `can't iterate from NilClass` on Rails 5.1.6 when using this gem...

Comment: Great! Does it work with deleted records between `MIN` and `MAX`?

Answer (score 1):

For MYSQL this worked for me:

```
User.order("RAND()").limit(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `.sample` on the records, like: `User.all.sample(10)`

Comment: this would take a long time because we're dealing with Ruby objects. If these objects are in the hundreds of thousands, this may break

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @maurimiranda `User.offset(rand(User.count)).first` is not good in case we need get 10 random records because `User.offset(rand(User.count) - 10).limit(10)` will return a sequence of 10 records from the random position, they are not "total randomly", right? So we need to call that function 10 times to get 10 "total randomly".

Beside that, offset is also not good if the random function return a high value. If your query looks like offset: 10000 and limit: 20 , it is generating 10,020 rows and throwing away the first 10,000 of them,
which is very expensive. So call 10 times offset.limit is not efficient.

So i thought that in case we just want to get one random user then `User.offset(rand(User.count)).first` maybe better (at least we can improve by caching User.count).

But if we want 10 random users or more then `User.order("RAND()").limit(10)` should be better.

Answer (score -4):

Here's a quick solution..  currently using it with over 1.5 million records and getting decent performance.  The best solution would be to cache one or more random record sets, and then refresh them with a background worker at a desired interval.

Created `random_records_helper.rb` file:

```
module RandomRecordsHelper

 def random_user_ids(n)
    user_ids = []
    user_count = User.count
    n.times{user_ids << rand(1..user_count)}
    return user_ids
 end
```

in the controller:

```
@users = User.where(id: random_user_ids(10))
```

This is much quicker than the `.order("RANDOM()").limit(10)` method - I went from a 13 sec load time down to 500ms.

Comment: Of course, this only works if your ids are auto-incrementing integers, start with 1 and there are no holes in the sequence.

Comment: Gotta downvote this because of the same sentiments as @SergioTulentsev. If you've ever destroyed any records then this method is unreliable, being that you could ask for 10 records and potentially not actually get 10 records. The speediness is nice but speed without correct results has no value, while correct results (even if they're slower than you'd like) does still have value.