# How to show posts onto a static page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static, posts

I have created a image uploading type website. I can login and upload images and it shows perfectly.

But I want to create a landing page for users who are not logged in and can see few images on the landing page.

And whenever someone uploads an image, it should update on the landing page as well. Kinda like in descending order.

I tried to create a static page on top of the `yield` in  the `views/layouts/application.html.haml` but it didn't work because whenever I'll upload something, it will show me the landing page then on the bottom, the form.

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

Comment: Fetch some images in controller action of the landing page. Then display them in the view.

Comment: @NitishParkar Can you please elaborate? A simple code snippet, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your root route points to your landing page,

```
root 'welcome#index'
```

In controller, fetch the image records you want to show on the landing page,

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @images = Image.last(10)
  end

end
```

Use them in views,

```
- @images.each do |image|
  # put them in img tag
```

Comment: @moose: based on your explanation I have posted some sample code. Hope it helps.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. But if I wanted to show random posts? Can you show me the code of Random posts?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641057/rails-select-random-record) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342270/rails-3-get-random-record)